# Angular 2 Routes - Cannot Match Any Routes RC4

Tags: angular

I am testing a really basic Angular2 app and ran into some trouble with routing. I stripped everything back so that I just have two test components. The project is RC4 and built with angular CLI. I had nightmares about this last night...It seems that it should be so easy to figure out but I can't see it. I feel like it has to do with app being in src folder? (app not really 'root'?)

Thank you for the help.

Error (from Chrome Dev)

```
zone.js:461 Unhandled Promise rejection: Cannot match any routes: '' ; Zone: angular ; Task: Promise.then ; Value: Error: Cannot match any routes: ''(…)

zone.js:463 Error: Uncaught (in promise): Error: Cannot match any routes: ''(…)
```

EDIT ***** FIXED THIS
  We fixed it doing a few things. (1) we added a default route to the routes array in app.routes.ts.

Project Structure is

```
SRC
   APP
     test.component.ts
     test2.component.ts
     app.routes.ts
```

App Routes:

```
import { provideRouter, RouterConfig } from '@angular/router';
import {Test2Component} from './test2.component';
import {TestComponent} from './test.component';

const routes: RouterConfig = [
{ path: '', component: TestComponent },
{ path: 'test2', component: Test2Component }
];

export const appRouterProviders = [
    provideRouter(routes)
];
```

TestComponent

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';

@Component({
  moduleId: module.id,
  selector: 'test-nav',
  templateUrl: 'test.component.html',
  directives: [ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]
})

export class TestComponent {}
```

TestComponent2

```
import {Component} from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    templateUrl: "test2.component.html",
})

export class Test2Component{}
```

HTML for Test Component Link

```
<a href="#" routerLink="/test2" routerLinkActive="active"><h1>test</h1></a>
```

```
Error when we click on the link from that HTML
zone.js:101 GET http://localhost:4200/test2.component.html 404 (Not Found)
```

Index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <base href="/">
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Webstimate</title>
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-2.2.0.min.js"></script>
  <script src="vendor/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="vendor/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <!--<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.2/jquery.min.js"></script>-->
  {{#unless environment.production}}
  <script src="/ember-cli-live-reload.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  {{/unless}}
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">

</head>
<body>
  <test-nav>Loading...</test-nav>
    {{#each scripts.polyfills}}<script src="{{.}}"></script>{{/each}}
    <script>
      System.import('system-config.js').then(function () {
        System.import('app/main');
      }).catch(console.error.bind(console));
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Main.TS

```
    import { bootstrap } from '@angular/platform-browser-dynamic';
    import { enableProdMode } from '@angular/core';
    import { appRouterProviders } from './app.routes';
    import { ROUTER_DIRECTIVES } from '@angular/router';


    if (environment.production) {
      enableProdMode();
    }

bootstrap(TestComponent, [appRouterProviders, ROUTER_DIRECTIVES]);
```

Comment: What is the folder structure that you are using?  Where are all of these files located?

Comment: All of the files are in the APP folder. APP folder is in a folder named SRC (created by the CLI). Index.HTML is the SRC folder.

Comment: we are getting somewhere. See above edits...cleared the 1st error about not finding routes for ''. Now we just have the error when clicking on the link (we feel it has to do with the base of the project being in SRC).

Comment: We figured it out...I am going to post a longer answer tomorrow so if anyone else runs into this they know what to do.

Comment: I got the exact same issue, would you mind sharing your solution melegant?

Comment: I've figured out that my router for some reason tries to go to a route called "Setup" every time I start my application. I have never had a route called Setup but I inserted one now and redirected that route to my home route and now I got a temporary solution atleast..

Comment: Hi J sorry I am on the road in another country so I was not able to post the code. Probably tonight. One issue was having default route to the same component as our startup component. We also took out router directives from main and just use it in the component that is using routerlink and router-outlet.

Comment: Hi J again. The trick was precompiling the routed components in the main calling form: ex   precompile: [ContentComponent, UserActivityComponent, DynamicShellComponent],